# Issue while using Date range filter in elasticsearch

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to logstash and elasticsearch. I have logline which I have parsed in logstash. See below example:
Log line:

```
20150727 020225108-0700 site1dir01 imqueueserv 4161 0 139965885622016 Note;MtaQueueDirRemoved(79/54) /xyz/user1/queue/deferred/MTA:rme=QS_P_GETQUEUEDMESSAGES:port=10003
```

Grok pattern I have written for it:

```
grok{
            match => ["message", "%{YEAR}%{MONTHNUM}%{MONTHDAY} %{USERNAME:Integerdata} %{HOST} %{WORD:servername} %{INT:processID}...%{INT:data} %{WORD:loglevel};%{WORD:traceName}\(.*\) %{GREEDYDATA:Logdata}",
            "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:mtaLogData}"]
        }
```

Now In Kibana, I am getting data for timestamp as this:

@timestamp  ==>  2015-07-27T02:02:25.812-07:00

Now when I fire below curl command in elasticsearch to get the data from specific dates, I get all records which should not happen.

My curl command as below:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_count?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
                "should" : [
                        {
                        "match" : {
                                "type" : "queueserverLog"
                        }} ,
                        {
                        "filtered" : {
                        "filter" : {
                                "range" : {
                                        "timestamp" : {
                                                "from" : "2015-07-23T00:00:01",
                                                "to" : "2015-07-23T23:59:59"
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        }
                        }
                ]
        }
    }
}'
```

Can anyone guide me as to get the data based on date filter ehat I need to do here?

Comment: Have you tried to use a `must` clause instead of a `should` clause?

Comment: Tried that also, then it shows count as 0.

Comment: Ok.. Got it... Curl command has to be like this:

Comment: Need to use must instead of should and @timestamp instead of timestamp.